# CSS for first table

Tags: css

I have a structure that looks like this:

```
<div class="foo">
    <table>
        //...
    </table>
    <table>
        //...
    </table>
</div>
```

What I want is to apply a specific css rule only on the first table, how could this be done?

Comment: Why not use a class or an id?

Answer (score 4):

I think this should do it.

```
 table:nth-of-type(1)
    {
        /*style away */
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using CSS3** like...

```
.foo table:first-child {
  // Do somthing
}
```

---

**Fallback :** (via using jQuery)

```
$('.foo table:first-child').addClass('first-child');
```

**So CSS like..**

```
.foo table:first-child, .foo table.first-child {
      // Do somthing
}
```

Comment: Please don't refer to w3schools. [Why not?](http://www.w3fools.com/)

Comment: @Bondye Oh Sorry, Dont know that before

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/tnjVR/

```
.foo table:first-child {
    color:Red;
}
```

Comment: This has the advantage of working on almost all CSS-enabled browsers, even old versions of IE. Note however that the selector matches any `table` element that is the first child of its parent and is a descendant of an element in class `foo`. So in a more complex situation, it could match too much.

Answer (score 1):

```
.foo > :first-child
```

or

```
.foo > table:first-of-type
```

The latter is in case you have a non-table element before `table` in `.foo`.  The former ensures that only children of `.foo` that are first children will be specified and not just any first-child descendant of `.foo`.

Answer (score 0):

`nth-of-type`, `first-child`, `nth-child`, or `first-of-type` would do it...

```
table:nth-of-type(1) {
    ...
}

table:first-of-type {
    ...
}

table:first-child {
    ...
}

table:nth-child(1) {
    ...
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/NX6cd/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

try like

```
.selector table:first-child {
color:Red;
}
```